# Cross Site Scripting in CSS Stylesheets

Tags: css, xss

Is it possible to use cross site scripting in a CSS stylesheet? For example a reference stylesheet contains malicious code, how would you do this?
I know you can use style tags but what about stylesheets?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From the [browser security handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1#Cascading_stylesheets)

> The risk of JavaScript execution. As a little-known feature, some CSS implementations permit JavaScript code to be embedded in stylesheets. There are at least three ways to achieve this goal: by using the expression(...) directive, which gives the ability to evaluate arbitrary JavaScript statements and use their value as a CSS parameter; by using the url('javascript:...') directive on properties that support it; or by invoking browser-specific features such as the [-moz-binding mechanism of Firefox](http://www.securiteam.com/securitynews/5LP051FHPE.html).

... and after reading that, I find this on StackOverflow. See [Using Javascript in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css#answer-482088)
In Firefox, you can use [XBL](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xbl/) to inject javascript in a page via CSS. However, the XBL file must reside in the same domain, now that [bug 324253 is fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324253).

There is another interesting (though different from your question) way to abuse CSS. See http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com/2009/12/generic-cross-browser-cross-domain.html. Essentially, you misuse the CSS parser to steal content from a different domain.

Comment: I've heard of that handbook but didn't think it was worth a read. Now I do. Thanks for the answer. :) So IE8 doesn't support expression() in standards mode. (Just thought I'd mention)

Answer (score 7):

The OWASP Mutillidae project has a Cascading Style Injection vulnerability example on page： http://localhost/mutillidae/index.php?page=set-background-color.php

Of course, you need to setup the env locally first. You can download and set it up on your localhost from the following link:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mutillidae_2_Project

Here is the relevant hint:
https://github.com/webpwnized/mutillidae/blob/main/includes/hints/cascading-style-sheet-injection-hint.inc

Comment: Don't know why downvote but the first link targets your localhost machine.

Comment: @Tomor It is an experimental environment and should be only used locally. I have added some explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! The last link (to github) is however dead now.

Comment: @greg Thanks for pointing that out. I tried to find a replacement for the link but failed... I guess one could still be able to find the hint inside the application.