# Executing JavaScript from CSS in Chrome, similarly to Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, security

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536237/putting-javascript-into-css) (where the answer links [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607894/cross-site-scripting-in-css-stylesheets)) discusses executing arbitrary JavaScript called from a CSS file using various hacks in IE and in Firefox, such as using `expression()`. (Someone in comments clarified that the correct names for these techniques are XBL in Firefox and HTC in IE)

How to do the same (execute arbitrary unsafe JS from CSS) in Chrome using client-side code only and using native methods without any additional libraries?

Comment: the question you linked to is not firefox/ie specific - any answer in that question is browser agnostic as the work is done on the server side (in most answers that I could be bothered to read)

Comment: @JaromandaX I've clarified a bit. The answer there links to an article about methods like expression() used in CSS.

Comment: You mean [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Using_XBL_from_stylesheets) in firefox? and HTC in IE?

Comment: _"How to do the same (execute arbitrary unsafe JS from CSS) in Chrome using client-side code only and using native methods without any additional libraries?"_ What is purpose of the process?

Comment: @guest271314 - clearly to execute arbitrary **unsafe** JS, perhaps to own all your bases?

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly

Comment: HTC doesn't work for IE after IE10, XBL can only be loaded using `file:///` scheme or from an add-on ... so, chrome isn't missing anything spectacularly useful

Comment: @K48 Why would you want to achieve such a requirement?

Comment: also, sXBL (a subset of XBL for SVG) and XBL 2.0 (a cross browser standards proposal) are dead, so nobody sees any use in such dubious functionality

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks! Didn't know that it's dead after IE10 and other limitations. That should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript in CSS isn't possible in modern browser - except for any currently supported URL parameters (e.g. [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)) where `javascript:` URLs will cause any script to be executed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32455401/413180), but I've summarised here.

`moz-binding` was possible in Firefox 2 & 3, and an identified flaw was later mitigated, however support was dropped in future versions.

HTML Components haven't been supported since Internet Explorer 10, so there is little point in developing a website that relies on this technology.

CSS Expressions are only supported in IE5/7 quirks/standards mode respectively.

Are you looking to create an exploit, or to achieve some functional requirement using CSS? If the former, concentrate on URL parameters or breaking out of the CSS context into JavaScript. Also UI redress may be possible to trick the user into believing site content you inject is authoritative. If the latter, then go down a different route rather than shoehorning CSS to acheive script execution.