# DOM and remove tag againnst xss attack way to optimize it?

Tags: php, dom, tags, detection, xss

A friend of me posted a code about how to prevent xss attack using DOM.

What do you think about this code ?
Can we optimize it ?

```
<?php
    function parseDoc(DOMDocument $codeHtml){
      $forbiddenTag=array('script');
      $forbiddenAttr=array('onmouseover','onmouseup','onclick');
      foreach($forbiddenTag as $tag){
        $liste=$codeHtml->getElementsByTagName($tag);
        foreach($liste as $element){
          $codeHtml->removeChild($element);
        }
      }
      stripAttr($codeHtml,$forbiddenAttr);
    }

    function stripAttr(DOMNode $root, array $forbiddenAttr){
     foreach($rootl->childNodes as $child){
        foreach($forbiddenAttr as $attr){
          if($child->hasAttribute($attr)) $child->removeAttribute($attr);

        }.
        if($child->hasChildNodes())strippAttr($child,$forbiddenAttr);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct way to combat XSS.

You're using a blacklist that will eternally fail to catch all ways to include scripts. For example, you're not catching the `onload` attribute or `javascript:` links. Instead, always use DOM methods to construct text nodes and attribute values, and you will be safe by default. If you want to have users allow formatted text, use a **whitelist** of allowed elements, attributes, and attribute values.

Comment: @Zeroth I don't know any php function by that name. Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: Sorry its late here and i didn't think well:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to use a list of all DOM events as a blacklist. Note that there are other ways than event properties (and weird stuff like `<s\0cript>` in some browsers or [JavaScript in style sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607894/cross-site-scripting-in-css-stylesheets)) to include JavaScript. Also, there will be new DOM events in the future which you can't possibly handle now. You should really use a whitelist instead.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to include JS on CSS sheets... Actually which DOM events could be really dangerous for XSS attack ?

Comment: @Zeroth All of them. Why don't you use a whitelist?

Comment: Use htmlpurifier instead. It's whitelist based. Building a blacklist of DOM events is a bad idea as HTML5 is constantly evolving and adding new events.