# Which browsers still support CSS expressions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-expressions

From a blog:

> The basic idea with CSS expressions is
>   that you will have calculation and
>   dynamic values for properties in the
>   CSS code, something that people have
>   found very useful. A simple example
>   can be implementing max-width behavior
>   in IE 6:
>
> ```
> width: expression(document.body.clientWidth > 1100)? "1100px" : "auto";
> ```

This is the first time I read about them. It seems IE used to support CSS expressions but dropped them in IE8. What other browsers still use them and are they generally a good or bad thing?

The [blog post](http://robertnyman.com/2007/11/13/stop-using-poor-performance-css-expressions-use-javascript-instead/) I got this from says the alternative is Javascript, but I thought CSS was more supported and therefore better than Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, it was only ever IE6/7 (maybe) 5.

I never thought they were a good thing. May as well just use JavaScript directly.

They are in fact implemented in JavaScript, and I'm pretty sure disabling JS disables these expressions.

The sample you posted...

```
width: expression(document.body.clientWidth >  1100)? "1100px" : "auto";
```

...is just a ternary operator that says *If the width is larger than 1100px, set it 1100px, otherwise set property to auto*.

To finish, no scripting language on the web is more widely supported than JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions are unique to IE and were dropped in 8:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082(VS.85).aspx#expressions

More about expressions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: In IE9, `calc` from the real standardized CSS specification was added to substitute it, but what does one do for IE8 to still support this without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has a similar setup, [XBL](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xbl/) - [check out this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css/482088#482088).  HTML5 editor Ian Hickson recently stirred things up a little by [releasing a new draft](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010JulSep/0675.html) of the W3C attempt to standardize XBL (see also [the WG response](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010JulSep/1008.html)), so we may ultimately see something similar to Microsoft 's expressions as part of the HTML5 family of technologies.

Comment: XBL is dead: https://bgrins.github.io/xbl-analysis/