# Find out the effective width of element and resize text in it

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'd like to find out the width of a TD which has defined `style='width: 200px;`, but the text makes it longer (no break). I want to find out the effective width and, as long it is bigger than 200px, shrink the text size in it for about 2px each time.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: You want to find it using JavaScript?

Comment: @Praveen I removed your addition in the tags of "expression" : OP didn't precise he wanted specifically them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in javascript but it's a little complex.

Here's the complete working example : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/kdrrA/

The HTML :

```
<table><tr><td id=txtcell nowrap><span id=txt>My long text is long. My long text.</span></td></tr></table>
<br>Font Size : <span id=mes></span>​
```

The CSS :

```
#txtcell{ max-width:200px;}
```

The javascript :

```
var fontSize = 20; 
var reduce = function() { 
    while ($('#txt').width() > 200) { 
        fontSize -= 1; 
        $('#txt').css('font-size', fontSize); 
    }
    $('#mes').html(fontSize); // this line is only for demonstration, remove it in "production"
}; 
reduce();
```

Note that I had to add a span in the cell because TD width computation by jquery doesn't work very well.

Comment: I've edited your JS a bit, because the Interval does have too much time so the user sees the interaction. With this, it works very well:
var fontSize = 20;
var reduce = function() {
    while ($('#txt').width() > 200) {
        fontSize -= 1;
        $('#txt').css('font-size', fontSize);
    }
    $('#mes').html(fontSize);
};
reduce();

Comment: OK. You may edit directly my answer if you think this may be useful for other people.

Comment: This answer is a perfect candidate for improvement by binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to make it. But if you wish to make it using CSS alone, you can use CSS expressions with `expression`.

```
td {width: expression(this.style.width);}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: CSS expressions are only compatible with Internet Explorer and even Microsoft dropped them long time ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810478/which-browsers-still-support-css-expressions