# Injecting HTML via CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to basically set the `content` of something with HTML from CSS. I'm currently doing the following:

```
.myclass {
    content "<img src=\"hello.png\"/>";
}
```

However, instead of the image, I see the literal text:

```
<img src="hello.png"/>
```

How can  I inject arbitrary HTML using CSS?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content

Comment: @SimonEdström unfortunately not. Output I'm building it for only supports HTML/CSS.

Comment: @PhilipBevan, yes I've seen that. Would I just have to encode my HTML somehow?

Comment: @PhilipBevan - Yes, exact duplicate.

Comment: @TKKocheran - Yes, you would have to encode it as escaped Unicode, just like the answer in that question says.

Comment: CSS is for layout and appearance (i.e. "style").  Not content.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. This question is about inject HTML tags, not HTML entities.

Comment: @TKKocheran- I woud trust the other answers here that say you cannot do it, I would recommend Rob W.'s answer and use background-image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HTML stores the data, and is the Model
CSS stores the styles, and is the View
JS stores the interactions, and is the Controller

If you're trying to add data to the page, it should be done via HTML. If you're simply trying to add an image as a style, use the `background-image` property. You don't need to inject an `<img>` element in the page to do that.

## Don't ever do this, *ever*

As far as being able to inject HTML into the page via CSS, it's not directly possible, however it's possible to add [JavaScript into the page using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css), which can then add HTML to the page.

I can't emphasize enough how *wrong* that approach would be.

Answer (score 7):

Unless there is some strange hack that I am not aware of, this cannot be done with pure CSS.

The `content` property is only able to insert text; if you try to put in HTML, it will be escaped.

That said, you *can* do something like this with pure CSS:

[image]

This is the CSS that can perform that effect:

```
.myClass:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  content: "";
  background-image: url("img.gif");
}
```

[You can see this in action on this jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/SvbNZ/).

Comment: Strange hack will require JavaScript, sadly.

Comment: Except Javasript is equipped to do this and doesn't need any strange hacks.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you can use a pseudo-class (eg [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore)), `background-image`, `display:block` and a fixed width and height to show the image.

Also, make sure that the colon `:` is added between `content`  and its value.

A relatively new concept at the horizon is the `element()` value for backgrounds. This will display HTML as if it were an image: See also [`-moz-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/element).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with print media and so I can't use the `:before` selector on my `@page @top-left` selector, I've tried :(

Comment: @TKKocheran Another exotic approach: Add a negative left margin to your element, and a positive left padding. Then add the background image on the element *itself*. Make sure that you use `background-repeat:no-repeat` to show the image only once.

Comment: The [evil button example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element#A_somewhat_more_bizarre_example) looks dangerous but is actually [harmless](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5026YYGWOTV).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. For example with Firefox

css

```css
#hlinks
{
  -moz-binding: url(stackexchange.xml#hlinks);
}
```

stackexchange.xml

```
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <binding id="hlinks">
    <content>
      <children/>
      <html:a href="/privileges">privileges</html:a>
      <html:span class="lsep"> | </html:span>
      <html:a href="/users/logout">log out</html:a>
    </content>
  </binding>
</bindings>
```

[**ref 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css)

[**ref 2**](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/master/moonch~1/palemo~1/profiles/default/chrome)

Comment: [`-moz-binding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-binding) is deprecated since Gecko 57 (Firefox 57 / Thunderbird 57 / SeaMonkey 2.54)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's not what it's for. The CSS is for the presentation layer while the HTML is the data layer.

Actually, you can, but just for characters, not HTML. You can use the [`content`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/content) property. With some CSS selectors like [`:before`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-before), you can do nice stuff like adding your own character as a bullet for your list. But not much more.