# Can browsers execute JS via CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Javascript in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css)

I was [reading about the Samy worm](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html) and it shows

```
<div id="mycode" expr="alert('hah!')"
  style="background:url('javascript:eval(document.all.mycode.expr)')">
```

Do ANY browsers support running javascript like this? I tried on the three i have installed (firefox, chrome and IE 8 i believe) and none of them execute anything. I'm unsure if i am doing it wrong but anyways

Can browsers execute any javascript in any way through CSS? which includes playing with mimes and putting javacript in css. I doubt any browsers do this (maybe ie6 did at one point?) but i like to ask to make sure.

Comment: Why don't you add this div with calculated values by/through Javascript?