# can we use "javascript" codes in css "background"?

Tags: javascript, css, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Javascript in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css)

is it possible to use `javascript` codes in css `background`?
mean something like this :

> style="background:url(javascript:---javascript codes---);"
>   does this syntax work or not?

thanks in advance

Comment: really really thanks - that was interesting.

Comment: i test it in FF 3 and IE 8 -> does not work.

Comment: do n't vote to close please -> there are 3 nice answers here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes, with an expression:

```
background: expression(JS code resulting in a vali background image string here)
```

However I think it only works in IE and it's very bad practice because it may have to re-evaluate the code hundreds of times every second.

Instead, you should have a suitable default there, and then use JavaScript later on the page to change it.

Comment: thanks for the answer / would you please give a workable example!

Comment: It should be noted that expressions have been unsupported since 2008, and don't work in modern versions of IE. I mean no offense, but I'm baffled by the fact that this was the *accepted* answer.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I didn't expect it to be the accepted answer either. I honestly expected it to be made a comment... But if it's for an intranet where the computers are on older IE (as is the unfortunate case of many companies) then it's perfect.

Comment: @Kolink That would be one scenario, though I wouldn't consider it *perfect* in that it further cements them into being unable to upgrade their browser at any time in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

You cant use JavaScript inside CSS. But if you want to change the background image using JavaScript following line will work,

```
document.getElementById("<element ID>").style.backgroundImage = "url(<url of image>)";
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Accessing the Style Attribute with JavaScript

You cannot use JavaScript *in* your CSS, but you can use JavaScript to *set* your CSS rules. For instance:

```
// Create CSS BackgroundImage Rule
var bg = "url('http://placekitten.com/200/300)";

// Apply Rule
document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundImage = bg;
```

#### Making Variables and Functions Possible in CSS

Additionally, there are a series of frameworks and tools that permit you to use functions and variables in CSS, such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

#### IE's Old (and dead since 2008) Dynamic Properties

The closest you'll get to having JavaScript *in* your CSS would be something [Dynamic Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (introduced in IE5), which have very poor support cross-browser, and are [no longer supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx) in modern versions of IE.

#### Quick and Easy CSS Modification with jQuery

If you need to do a lot of modifications to your styles with JavaScript, by and large people are moving towards adopting frameworks to assist with that. For instance, one popular framework is jQuery, which permits things like:

```
$("#foo").css('background-color', 'red');
```

As well as mass-assignment through objects:

```
var color  = "#ffe", 
    border = "5px solid #ccc";

$("#foo").css({ 'background-color': color, 'border-left': border });
```

Comment: hi, thanks... so what's about Kolink's answer?

Comment: @MoonLight That would be the Dynamic Properties mentioned in my answer. It isn't a widely supported feature, and as such you should avoid it.