# redirect pages from weblog to domain with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to redirect pages from my weblog to a domain which i have on it.
for example this url:

```
the-vampire-diaries.mihanblog.com/post/300
```

should redirect to this:

```
tvdfans.ir/post/300
```

the thing is i only have access to the style codes not the files.
i want a JavaScript code that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this using javascript

```
**Example:**
<script langauge="text/javascript">
window.location.replace(someUrl");
</script>
```

Comment: this script changes the whole address... i want to change the beginning of the url ...
for example this:
the-vampire-diaries.mihanblog.com/post/300

should change to :

tvdfans.ir/post/300

and also this:
the-vampire-diaries.mihanblog.com/post/301
should change to :
tvdfans.ir/post/301


not only the first page of site

Answer (score 1):

You can't write javascript code in stylesheets.

If you have access to an html template, you can just use

```
<script>
    document.location.hostname = 'example.org';
</script>
```

Comment: @Derek I've completed the answer with a workaround if 'style' means 'html template'

Comment: Mael - Actually you can somehow run JavaScript in CSS with hacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css ;)

Comment: @Derek True, but it only works on IE, and even this browser has dropped support in the last version :)

Comment: I was surprised that Firefox also support putting JavaScript in CSS!

Comment: i have access to javascript yes .
this script changes the whole address... i want to change the beginning of the url ...
for example this:
the-vampire-diaries.mihanblog.com/post/300

should change to :

tvdfans.ir/post/300

and also this:
the-vampire-diaries.mihanblog.com/post/301
should change to :
tvdfans.ir/post/301


not only the first page of site

Comment: @ArmanJelodar Have you tried my script ? I've test it on IE9, firefox and chrome, and it works as specified. Please notice that the variable which is modified is `document.location.hostname` and not the full `document.location`.