# Using JavaScript in CSS file

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Javascript in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css)

I am developing an android app from Phonegap.
I need to set the width of a container relatively: find the width of a container and set width of the required container in proportion to it.
I can do this easily in JavaScript.
But i need to do this in CSS code, is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: Yes it's possible, IE and Firefox both support something in that direction.
NO don't use it. It isn't a mainstream accepted functionality and it's a dirty solution to your problem. Can't you have an external JavaScript file to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try LESS dynamic stylesheet language: http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, less can do it, but I presume that isn't an option because it requires rethinking your entire styling approach.

There is a link given in a comment, but my advice to you is - it is way too complex to be done the way you wish. You should probably rethink the approach to alter the property directly with javascript.

IT would be the cleanest solution.