# Insert HTML with XBL

Tags: html, css, xbl

Following [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/482088), I was able to insert some text with Firefox like this

css

```css
body
{
  -moz-binding: url(foo.xml#bar);
}
```

foo.xml

```
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl">
  <binding id="bar">
    <content>
      Hello world
    </content>
  </binding>
</bindings>
```

However I could not find a way to insert HTML rather text using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I just need to declare the [**XHTML namespace**](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Adding_HTML_Elements)

```
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <binding id="bar">
    <content>
      <html:b>
        Hello world
      </html:b>
    </content>
  </binding>
</bindings>
```