# Generate random color with pure CSS (no javascript)?

Tags: css, random, colors

Is it possible to generate random color with pure CSS and without using javascript? It's probably impossible but I'm still curious.

Comment: It can't be done. CSS is pretty much static.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css

Comment: @Blender That is not actually *pure* CSS though.

Comment: @Boaz: Not pure CSS, but it's as close as you can get.

Comment: @Blender Well, OP clearly says *no javascript* :)

Comment: Use some javascript, it wont hurt :) http://jsbin.com/iyexum/1

Comment: Did you managed to do something ?

Answer (score 19):

This isn't really possible in pure CSS.

However, using a pre-processor like SASS ([example](http://pankajparashar.com/posts/random-colors-sass/)) or LESS ([example](https://gist.github.com/juanbrujo/7e4e17428dc8881d0e7e)) can generate random colors for you because they are built using scripting languages. Keep in mind that this value is then not random for each user or visit, unless the CSS file is generated for each user or visit individually (which is less common).

---

One side note is the possibility for using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). We can declare a CSS variable by saying:

```
html {
  --main-bg-color: brown;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
html {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Now we can change it using JS:

```
// From http://stackoverflow.com/a/5365036/2065702
const randomColor = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16); 

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-bg-color', randomColor);
```

Note that you can also create CSS variables for specific elements, not just the root document element.

Or you could use a completely different way of selecting a random color (like user input). This allows for possibilities like theming.

Comment: there is no color change, any help?

Comment: @sanojlawrence It's impossible to help blindly. You should probably create a new question about your problem including a [minimal example of your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6):

Not really. Dynamism can only be implemented with the support of scripting.

Answer (score 6):

```
<body style='background-color:<?php printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0x222222 )); ?>'>
```

Using PHP

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly random but with CSS:

Step 1 - Select queried backgrounds, order them in sequence and adjust the frequency

```
    @keyframes bgrandom {
    0% { background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 0%); }
    50% { background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 0%); }

    55% { background: linear-gradient(90deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 0%); }
    80% { background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.96)  50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 0%); }

    85% { background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.94) 0%); }
    100% { background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.94) 0%); }
    }
```

Step 2 - Launch the animation(length animationName repeatMode)

```
    #element{  animation: 1.2s bgrandom infinite; }
```

Easy to use, customize and works great. 
Similar technique can be used for sliders, spinners, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As bosco-mabutao mentioned, without a script you cannot currently achieve dynamism, however, if you inject an inline script within your index.html before loading react it will be instant and you won't see the pink background.

```js
function setRandomBackground() {
  const colors = [
    "#ffd7d5",
    "#ffe9d6",
    "#ffffd1",
    "#d6ffda",
    "#d7eeff",
    "#dad6ff",
    "#ffd6e8",
    "#f5f5dc",
    "#f4e4e4",
    "#e4e6f4" 
  ];

  const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
}

setRandomBackground();
```