# have a different colour for every line

Tags: css, database, list, colors

i have this code which shows data from a database. the code below is from the viewer side and there is no backend and retrieval. i was wondering how i can have every different entered result as a different colour. it is like different comments. i have word wrap on i don't want every single line to be a different colour i need every new comment ill show you the code below. i am getting the data from a database and the results get inputed as a list.

```html
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#load_results").load("db_results.php");
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>

<div id="aline">
        <div id = "load_results"></div>
        
        </div >
```

i have looked everywhere to find an answer but i can't what will i have to add to do this. i have tried multiple ways which i used to change colour but i can't seam to get it right. at this stage all i have in css is the word wrap since i can't seam to add any colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your db_results.php, but why do you not put it into a, let's say table or spans or divs or whatever and alternate the colors of each row by CSS ?

The code snippet is shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084318/1203816

Comment: i want the colours to be random

Comment: stays the same, but you have to change the fixed background-color to something like background-color:<?php printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0x222222 )). Source of this snippet :http://stackoverflow.com/a/20829687/1203816, so not tested by myself

Comment: it sets the background-color to a random value using php's random function. If you do not have php included you can get the same by using javascript or jquery.