# How can I secure user customizable public stylesheet from using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, xss

I want to give an ability for users of a site to be able to theme their pages using css. However, after reading [this excerpt on xss from stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css#answer-482088) I am trying to find a way that prevents this completely. How should I go about detecting and blocking any javascript from the input or reducing any effects other than style? Thanks.

Comment: Are you working within a framework? What server-side language are you using?

Comment: A half baked one, and php and python. Language doesn't matter a whole lot, if someone has made a good parser I can offload it to whatever needed if it is more than a hundred lines or so. I just for the life of me cannot find any good writing / suggestions on this broad problem.

Comment: Hm. You could use the PLY lexer/parser for Python to define your own rules to eliminate the malicious JS? Or another way might be to use a regex on submitted CSS, looking for URLs - if any aren't relative links (i.e. *within* your site) then sub them out.

Comment: @AlexLynham Yes, those are certainly things that could work. However, writing an xss parser with the changing landscape in browsers seems to be a bit of a risk. Website filtering would / could work, but from what I remember (which may now be irrelevant) was that there were craptons of hacks for injection. Hmm. XSS parsing seems so easy and at the same time, so hard to do correctly.