# How can I add an "onclick" in an input tag?

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox, onclick

I am trying to insert

```
onclick="countCheckboxes()"
```

within the input tag. Is there any way to do this in CSS? I tried the following, but didn't work:

```
input[type=checkbox]:after {
content: "onclick="countCheckboxes()"";}
```

So that it would eventually output this

```
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="countCheckboxes()">
```

This is for a Wordpress form. Maybe I could add something in the functions.php template to enable me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate Javascript in css. Please refer to this for more information: [Using Javascript in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css)

I am guessing that you want to keep your markup clean of JS? If so, the best thing would be to abstract the JS from your markup in a separate js file. There you can navigate the dom and append functions whichever way you require. You can do this with either vanilla Javascript or a JS framework(like Jquery) which simplifes the process a lot.

I'm happy to set up a demo if you wish to learn how.