# How to conditionally add css class in view in web2py?

Tags: css, web2py

In a web2py view, is there a concise way to add a css class to an html tag based on a conditional? I'm thinking something like this in pseudocode:

```
<div class="details {{if product.inventory == 0 then 'highlight'}}">...</div>
```

if product.inventory == 0 then the view will generate the following html:

`<div class="details highlight">`

otherwise:

`<div class="details">`

I know I can use a plain old if block in the view but I'm looking for a concise way to do this. Alternatively is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
<div class="details{{=' highlight' if product.inventory == 0 else ''}}">
```

Comment: thanks tried something like this but I think I was missing the else clause.  Appears it's mandatory in this situation?

Comment: That's a Python [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (also known as a *ternary* operator), which does require an `else` (otherwise, the value in case the condition is false would be unknown). There are other approaches (e.g., you could define a variable in an if/else clause and stick the variable there).

Answer (score 0):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476289/2792719)

this (js in css) is only supported in IE though. Why not just have a javascript function that does the job?

Comment: Then you can't do it in css. Probably only in code behind if you want to avoid js completely.

Comment: @nevercode, @User is not using JS in CSS -- the `{{...}}` delimiters are part of web2py's server-side templating system.

Comment: @Anthony sorry about the confusion. I was talking about the answer link that I posted which talks about js in css.