# Is it possible to implement javascript through the 'style' parameter?

Tags: javascript

For an education hacking challenge I need to implement javascript in my `style` attribute.

How can I do this?

```
<a id="bb" style ="javascript"> alert('test') </a>
```

Comment: How do you mean? What have you tried?

Comment: not clear: do you need to highlight the javascript code (if so then look on google for _syntax highlighter_) or do you need to create a styled alert?

Comment: Can you give more information?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.234_-_CSS_Escape_And_Strictly_Validate_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Style_Property_Values provides a full list of XSS vulnerabilities and how they are implemented

Comment: He wants to execute Javascript through the `style` attribute, apparently...

Comment: maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css

Comment: @Matheus208 Exactly. 
I'm almost through a hack and my lector told me I should use the 'style' tag to perform the attack

Comment: As far as I know, most, if not all of the vulnerabilities your instructor is thinking of were plugged. It's not possible to execute JavaScript from a style selector anymore (as far as I know).

Comment: Take a look at @RGraham 's answer. I could not replicate the behaviour from  there, but you might have a better idea on what to look into (or it might have been fixed on modern browsers). Can you use any browser? Try older version of IE, it used to be the less secure

Comment: I'm looking to bypass the regex <a style = ""> Is there any chance I could do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to learn how is render html code and the style attribute. And then find a way to execute your own javascript code.

http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Rendering_engines